# Embedding Slideshow , broken images

Tags: image, include, indexing, slideshow, byte-order-mark

i need help in this situation , i am embedding a slideshow using wowslider ... its included through the index.php file

```
 <div class="content">
<?php
include 'includes/aside.php';
include 'includes/widgets/slideshow.html';  
?>
</div>
```

[Link of the broken images](http://modelcharm.com)

[Direct link for the slideshow , works properly](http://modelcharm.com/includes/widgets/slideshow.html)

(Note : this is just a test slideshow not the final one . )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

include "$root/includes/aside.php";

include "$root/includes/widgets/slideshow.html";

***change the links in slider to absolute links.

Comment: Same problem , nothing is changed